# None of react native tutorial to integrate google maps works

Tags: react-native

it's been 12 hours non stop that i'm trying to make just a react native app with google maps, i've tried everything but nothing works

Does anyone have a simple project that has google map on it and i will replace the key, or send me a working tutorial please.

I'm using Expo and react native 0.55

Comment: Please provide the code you've done. Otherwise, it's hard to help you. Using MapView and Expo, you don't have to provide any api key

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic on SO. If you are having problems with your code please share the relevant part so people can help with that.

Comment: here's the last tutorial i followed, i have the same code 

http://nobrok.com/add-google-maps-and-map-kit-to-react-native-app-in-10-steps/